# in which case to use objectId over string validation in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, validation, nosql

getting validation failed error while insertion in comment collection.

I am having 3 collections(Rule, Page and Comment).

**Rule collection:-**
{validator: { $or: [ { r_name: { $type: "string"} } ] }}

**Page collection:-**
{validator: { $or: [ { url: { $type: "string"} } ] }}

**Comment collection:-**
{ validator: { $or: [ { rule_id: { $type: 'objectId' } }, { page_id: { $type: 'objectId' } } ] } }

insertion in Comment collection:-

```
process
    .myDb
    .comment
    .insertOne({
        rule_id: "5a035eb6eea8b4ba363e6f8d",
        page_id: "5a035effeea8b4ba363e6f8e"
    })
    .then(resp => {
        console.log('Success');
    })
    .catch(() => {
        // HERE i am getting "Document failed validation"
        console.log('Error');
    });
```

Doubts:-

- I am not sure what kind of validation to be used in this case for comment collection.
- what is the difference between validation $type objectId & string.
  as far as I found objectId is binary but the string would be character array implementation.
- when to use objectId?
- in RDBMS we would create a foreign key how to achieve the same in MongoDB.
- this can be solved by mongoose plugin but I cant use that because of some other reasons.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in strings where your validator expects ObjectIds. You can however compute the corresponding ObjectId from a given string by using `ObjectId(stringValue)`.

In your code:

```
process
  .myDb
  .comment
  .insertOne({
    rule_id: ObjectId("5a035eb6eea8b4ba363e6f8d"),
    page_id: ObjectId("5a035effeea8b4ba363e6f8e")
  })
  .then(resp => {
    console.log('Success');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // HERE i am getting "Document failed validation"
    console.log('Error');
  });
```

You might need to prefix `ObjectId()` with a module name depending on how you import mongoDB etc., but you get the idea.

See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#ObjectId) for reference.